# VisualStudio 2013 Express phone emulator - device not found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

1. Step1: Installed VisualStudio 2013 Express for Windows along with
   Update 2.
2. Step2: Created a blank Windows Phone App.
3. Step3: Deployed the app to the Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB.

The Emulator Displays with the message 'Windows Phone is Starting'. Times out after about 5 minutes with the following error messages:

> Error: DEP6100: The following unexpected error occurred during
>   bootstrapping stage 'Connection to the device':
>
> Error: DEP6200: Bootstrapping 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed.
>   Device cannot be found.  App deployment failed. Please try again.

Hyper-V Manager shows the phone emulator running when the app is deployed to the 
Phone Emulator.

Running my existing phone 8.0 apps with VisualStudio 2012 Professonal through the
phone emulator stopped working after installing VisualStudio 2013 Express with Update 2.
I get this error:

> Windows Phone Emulator is unable to connect to the Windows Phone
>   operating system:
>        The phone did not respond to the connect request.
>        Some functionality might be disabled.

Tried running as administrator and repairing VisualStudio 2013 Express with no effect of this problem.

Anyone having similar issues ?

Comment: You should look at this article it helped me out! http://daxdude.blogspot.com/2015/01/error-dep6100-bootstrapping-0x80131622.html  basically make sure that your vEthernet for Windows Phone in network connections is enable!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem just now. Please take all windows update. Reboot, and check again for any remaining update. This was a bug earlier as well so microsoft fixed it in first update of windows 8.1

Then check any remaining extension update for your visual studio 2013. update there as well.

Try opening a sample app, it should work.

Regards
Kajal

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem . first i fixed it with:

- Updating windows
- Uninstall / install Windows Phone SDK 8
- Remove and add Hyper-v again ( maybe it is not necessary )

But problem came back  and instead of previous solution i fixed the issue with :

- going to windows firewall and then click on "restore defaults"

Answer (score 0):

Open Hyper-V manager. Look at all the emulators that are running and turn them all off.

Then open visual studio and deploy your app.

This will start a fresh instance of Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with VisualStudio 2013 Professional and the latest Windows Phone 8.1 SDK and emulators (as of December 2014).

In my case I fixed it by changing the virtual switch 'WinPhoneEmulatorSwitch' in Hyper-V Manager from  'Internal network' to 'Private network'.

I found this solution at [pekari.wordpress.com](http://pekari.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/62/)

Comment: In my case (VS2015 RC, Win10 emulator) it was in 'Private' and changing it to 'Internal' fixed my issue

Answer (score 0):

I had your same problem and after many attempts resolved it this way:

1. Deactivate Hyper-V (and restart computer);
2. Go in the Device Manager and open the Network Adapters, here uninstall *everything* with the name "Hyper-V...", this will allow us to reactivate Hyper-V without any conflict;
3. Enable Hyper-V (and restart computer);

Finally launch the emulator (if it is the first time you launch it you will have to wait 5-10 minutes, so be patient and wait for it to load all apps it need).