# Windows Phone Emulator not starting

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, emulation, windows-phone-8.1

When I run the emulator from the VS13 hangs self in "Windows Phone OS is Starting" but in Hyper-v manager is running properly and then keep getting two errors

Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Emulator 8.1 WVGA 4 inch 512MB' failed. Device cannot be found. App deployment failed. Please try again.

Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
SmartDeviceException - App deployment failed. Please try again.

Help!

Comment: I'd suggest that you reinstall the virtual phone packages.

Comment: I did that but the problem was not solved

Answer (score 3):

1. Repair the Visual Studio
2. Download and install this emulator (Microsoft Emulator - Windows 10.0.26624)
   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=619310

Answer (score 2):

The solution is removing a duplicated route.

1. List item
2. Run "cmd.exe" as administrator
3. Type "route print"
4. If you see two identical routes from 169.254.0.0 like here:

---

```
Persistent Routes:
Network Address  Netmask      Gateway Address  Metric
169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0  192.168.1.47     1
169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0  192.168.1.44     1
```

4. (b) Then remove both routes with "route delete 169.254.0.0"
5. Remove Hyper-V (go to "programs and features")
6. Restart system
7. Install Hyper-V
8. Restart system

Now you can deploy and debug your windows phone project on the emulator.

Comment: Reinstalling Hyper V is quite extreme. In my experience I found that the route in question was being shared with of all things my Corporate VPN client.  On disconnecting the client and then re-running the solution it was successfully deployed to the emulator.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the two errors you're getting have to do with two components of the Windows Phone VM.

For the first error, i don't know exactly what failed but it sounds like the VM image might not be working as VS is expecting, one thing you can do for this is simply open Hyper-V manager and delete the VM, when you start debugging again from VS, it will create the VM Image again according to the specifications of the device you're emulating.

But pay attention to the second error:

I have had that error lots of times, but that mostly presents even if the VM is successfully launched by VS, but there is an issue communicating with it through the virtual switch that is created for it and that can be managed in Hyper-V on the virtual switches section.

So in this case, once again, you can solve this issue by deleting the virtual switch in Hyper-V manager and VS will recreate it when you start debugging again.

I'm sorry i don't have a definitive answer for you with detailed steps but deleting the virtual switches and VMs works most of the time since VS does all the configuration for you when trying again, but if that fails, [check this guide at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx). I hope you get it working, it is a serious pain to deal with those issues for a while when you're just trying to test your apps.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be problems/conflicts with Windows Update and reboots during the setup phase of the update 2 of VS2013 bringing WP8.1.

Many people have the same problem:

- Case 1: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/872213/vs-2013-update-2-fails-to-connect-to-wp8-1-emulator
  ==> Solved by a reboot, even if the user had already done the reboot after installing WP8.1 VM
- Case 2: [VisualStudio 2013 Express phone emulator - device not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621874/visualstudio-2013-express-phone-emulator-device-not-found)
  ==> Solved by a reboot by Kajal Sinha

Can you reboot your machine, check any pending windows update, and try again?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have resolved this issue by removing all virtual machine in Hyper V manager as suggested by this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21084481/4562521

1. Open Hyper V Manager (click Start, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Hyper-V Manager)
2. Delete all installed Virtual Machines
3. Delete all Virtual Switches
4. Restart system
5. Rerun visual studio

Comment: Because removing all virtual machine created, solve on my computer this issue:  VS13 hangs self in "Windows Phone OS is Starting" but in Hyper-v manager is running properly. I'll change  this post  reply as you suggest. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem many times, and the main cause is anti-virus firewall settings.

Windows phone emulator will creates virtual network adapters, and independent anti-virus firewall does not allow access to these adapters.

To solve the issue, uninstall or disable anti-virus software including windows defender.