# Windows Phone deploy Issue

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I have a strange issue that I can not seem to find any record of but it has now happened to me on two separate machines! I am building Windows Phone 8.1 apps and testing them on a physical device. This works fine for a time until at some point with no warning i am unable to deploy to the phone and the console shows the errors below!

```
Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on. 

Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
```

Now this would lead me to believe that the cable has fallen out or its just become disconnected however it hasn't and im sure of that because i can still use it as a storage device to transfer pictures. Restarting the devices has zero effect and the only thing that worked on the first machine i tried was reformatting the pc and starting from scratch which i really dont have the time to do again!

Comment: Did you unlock the device? I mean you cannot deploy when you lock the screen.

Comment: Yes it is both developer unlocked and the screen is unlocked when I try to deploy!

Comment: check this question as it is related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621874/visualstudio-2013-express-phone-emulator-device-not-found

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I've had some problems sometimes registering some WP devices as developer devices. I've never had this particular error, but maybe this will work.

When the device is connected to the computer, in the taskbar click in the icon which shows that a device is connected (the one where you can "Safely remove" the device) and right click on it and select the show devices and printers option. When it opens, you will see all the windows phone devices you have connected to the computer. Disconnect your device and uninstall it and its drivers by selecting the appropriate option after right clicking on it.

Connect it again, it should now install its drivers again.

Update 1 :-

[image: Remove Device Option]

Comment: Fantastic who knew such a litre issue could cause so many problems haha thanks!

Comment: Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: *by selecting the appropriate option after right clicking on it.* - what is the appropriate option?

Comment: @TimCastelijns Please check the updated answer. There is an option to "Remove Device".

Comment: After removing the device then reinstalling the drivers, I still encounter the issue. It just takes a lot longer to deploy then I get the error again eventually. Hopefully I find a fix.

Comment: @LeviFuller what is the error that you get exactly?

Comment: @kshitijgandhi Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
DeviceException - 0x89731B01 AND Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731B01

Comment: @kshitijgandhi This is deploying to a Lumia 950XL. It worked the first day I was playing around with it, but no longer. I've tried removing the device so it reinstalls, restarting the computer and phone, and also tried Turning Developer Mode off -> trying it (same error) -> Turning it on again (same again)

Comment: @LeviFuller If possible, try (a) deploying app to the device on a different computer, (b) reset the phone to factory settings and try again, (c) Did you turn the developer mode On/Off on the device itself or via Windows Phone Developer Registration tool - if not done via the tool then try that, I haven't had a change to use a device Windows 10 Mobile  - only tried developer preview.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but solved it. Went to Control Panel > Device manager > Portable devices and uninstalled the phone. Plugged the phone back in and everything worked on both 2013 and 2015 Community.

It's taken me all day to find this though :-)

Comment: I uninstalled the phone, restarted the computer and plugged the phone. Also, I changed the name of the device, Windows 10 Mobile instead of Windows Phone. This name can be changed pressing on the popup when the phone is plugged for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get that, too.
Here's how I fix it (phone remains connected via USB)

1. switch phone to airplane mode, then deploy. If that fails:
2. switch phone to airplane mode, reboot phone, stay in airplane mode, then deploy