# Developer Unlock Windows Phone 8 getting 0x80004005

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

My device is Lumia 920, running WP8.1 GDR2, laptop OS Win8.1 Pro. I tried unlocking it through VS2013 developer unlock in TOOLS tab, it returns the error shown below:

[image]

It says "unknown error, please try register again." Error code is 0x80004005, does anyone know what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be the non-ASCII characters I had in my device name. I changed it back to English and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error may occur when the Visual Studio tools are not up to date.

Try going to `Tools > Extensions` and `Updates`.. and into the updates, ensure also that the phone is up to date as conflicts with this can often cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems sometimes registering some WP devices as developer devices. I've never had this particular error, but maybe this will work.

Check my answer on this question -

[Windows Phone deploy Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292782/windows-phone-deploy-issue/30303946#30303946)

When the device is connected to the computer, in the taskbar click in the icon which shows that a device is connected (the one where you can "Safely remove" the device) and right click on it and select the show devices and printers option. When it opens, you will see all the windows phone devices you have connected to the computer. Disconnect your device and uninstall it and its drivers by selecting the appropriate option after right clicking on it.

Connect it again, it should now install its drivers again.