# Can deploy to Windows phone on one machine but not another?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, mobile, windows-phone-8.1, windows-mobile

I have been developing a Windows phone app on my lunch breaks at work and spare time at home. The project is stored in my Dropbox so it's the same on both pcs. At work when I debug/deploy to the device everything is fine and dandy. At home however I get the following.

```
  Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Connecting to the device': 
  SmartDeviceException - Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on. 
  Error : DEP6200 : Boostrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found. Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.
```

Now in both cases I'm using the same version of the SDK and of VS on the same Microsoft account on the same phone on the same project. But it doesn't work.

I have reinstall the SDK twice now to no avail.

When I run the device registration I get the following message.

> Unable to connect to a phone. Make sure the Windows Phone IP over USB transport service is running

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, has anyone run into this before? Any ideas of a fix for the issue?

Update:

I have uninstalled 2013 r4 and installed 2015. I have done a hard reset on my phone. I have run Windows Update and I'm up to date. I have tried making brand new projects as some of the posts suggest, to no avail. Same issue occurs, except now my emulators get:

> The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '184901A8-DC44-4CED-869E-DC7733D048D6'

I'm guessing the next step is reinstalling Windows, I think I'll just wait till Windows 10 comes out.

Comment: Yep both have 8.1 Pro

Comment: @user3956566 I have removed and re added in device manager and tried to update the drivers in device manager. Is there a specific page where the downloads sit?

Comment: Just a quick update I may have accidentally destroyed my windows phone in a renovation "incident" haha ill be waiting to the new windows 10 phones come out to replace it. As a result im afraid this question may remain unanswered for all time :(

Answer (score 2):

Possible Fixes:
1.Try reconnecting your phone.
2. try re registering your phone as developer device
3. try this fix

> https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Phone_Testing/Configuring_IP_over_USB

Comment: then may be you should try reinstalling vs or try a new update

Comment: Man thats such a hassle haha ill reinstall vs on the weekend and see how I go :).

Comment: did you try the new 2015rc if not try it .. i dint have any problem till now

Comment: Just installed 2015 same issue. :(

Comment: try playing around with the usb drivers maybe .... and for the emulators wih the hyper-v, Go to connection ad sharing settings and then change adapter settings ... in the adapters check the one related to emulator..

Answer (score 1):

Testing apps on windows phones can be frustrating. One common problem I get is the need to reinstall drivers for the phone.  I think this may be your problem.

The other problem similar to this I've encountered, was when registering for windows phone not using the correct version on that pc for 8.0 or 8.1.

Aside from this, there is a list with links provided that may help you. Let us know how you get on.

This link [Problems and fixes when registering a Windows Phone 8 device to deploy/debug applications](http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/28/problems-and-fixes-when-registering-a-windows-phone-8-device-to-deploydebug-applications/) covers the major issues, some mentioned by Akash.

The following is a summary of the points discussed in the above link:

1. Windows Phone IP Over USB Transport(IpOverUsbSvc) service is running
2. Phone name is already in use by this account
3. Too many phones have already been registered with your account
4. Device lockscreen has to be unlocked (and it is unlocked)
5. Can’t find any devices

Point 5 is also addressed in this answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/30303946/3956566.

**Update after comment**

The other thing that you may need to do is:
1. make sure you have all **your updates in Windows**.
2. Make sure you have all **[VS updates](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/915388/cant-deploy-to-windows-phone-8-1-device-lumia-icon)**.
3. reinstall VS.
4. Reinstall any .net framework packages for VS.

The first two are the most likely things.
If worse comes to worse, to reinstall windows.

I have needed to do all of the above at one time or another to fix various issues. Painful, yes.

And don't forget to [reboot your machine.](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/872213/vs-2013-update-2-fails-to-connect-to-wp8-1-emulator)

Let me know if this works. There MUST be a solution.

I know what you mean about the phone appearing in explorer, update anyway, won't hurt to reinstall them.

Comment: In relation to "reinstall drivers for the phone" i have manually removed and uninstalled the device from device manager then re-installed the drivers automatically. I couldn't find on the net any where for specific updated drivers.  As for the points. 1 it is running i have tried restarting. 2 how do i check what phones are used by this account? 3 There is only one phone on the account. 4 Its unlocked :). 5 the device appears in explorer and windows recognizes its a windows phone so assume that part is all good :).