# Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found

Tags: deployment, windows-10, uwp

I've read every StackOverflow that I could find on this issue, but I still can't work it out.

I'm trying to deploy an app to actual device (*NOT* emulator). But I receive the following error when i try to build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '30F105C9-681E-420b-A277-7C086EAD8A4E'.': 
SEHException - External component has thrown an exception.  App1
```

and

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error       Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found.    App1
```

It's worth mentioning that I went from Windows 7 to Windows 10. It's also worth mentioning that my computer was missing the IpOverUsbSvc.exe (not just the registry post, but the actual service was missing). Couldn't find any way to get this back so, so my colleague sent over the .exe and the DLLs and I placed it in it's location. And the service is now running and no longer gives any errors. My device is recognized by the PC, it's running Windows 10 Mobile (but I've also tried with a device running Windows 8.1).

Specs on PC:

- Windows 10 Pro (Build 10240)
- Using Visual Studio 2015
- UWP Tools

Any suggestions to fix my nightmare? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have installed the latest SDK?
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview

Comment: Yes reinstalled the whole thing yesterday. No difference. :(

Comment: I have the same trouble. The solution was to install the latest SDK and Emulators

Comment: Same here, i can start the 10240 Emulators abut the 10586 Emulators does not load fully, just the start screen and in the end the app cannot be deployed :/ this is frustrating as the Emulators never where worse then now for WP :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally managed to find a solution to this illusive bug.

It seems that if I didn't have the Windows Phone 8.1 Tools installed I couldn't build to an ARM device (not even Windows 10 Mobile).

So my step to solve this was:
Go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio ... 2015 -> Modify. And then select the Windows Phone 8.1 Tools.

Pretty pissed that one can't get a reasonable error message when things like this is missing.

Comment: It wasn`t what solved my issue but it got my attention to check the "Solution Platforms" - it was on ARM instead of x86 which I needed in order to check on my desktop. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Steps that helped me. I have windows 10 mobile build 10581 (and now 10586) installed on phone

1. Turn off Developer mode on your phone.
2. Deploy app (UWP or SL) by VS2015 -> Error.
3. Turn on Developer mode on your phone.
4. Deploy app (UWP or SL) by VS2015 -> Working.

**If you change another device or re-connect you must close VS2015, re-launch and do again!**

Comment: That helped me! <3 almost real-time answers

Comment: This bug haunted me for more than a month. Had to go back to Windows 8.1 and back again to build 10166 so many times... The important thing here is to always close VS and force it to deploy without developer mode.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 update 1 released. And there this bug should be fixed https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: I did take up the update, but only after registering and de-registering the phone I could resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: How do you turn off developer mode?

Comment: Device Settings -> Update & Security -> For developers

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue after updating my device to win10 ver:10.0.10581.0. I tried many things but finally after installing latest sdk and emulators i got it working. You may try installing from this page sdk and emulator:

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-developer-preview

**Somehow the new emulators were not visible in vs, they got visible after few restarts and then on device debugging started to work.**

But one problem still remain from me that vs crashes after ending debug session with device.

Answer (score 1):

desktop-->my computer--> right click--> management--> service--> start the service  Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (`IpOverUsbSvc`) although maybe the `starttype` is set as automatic

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there are many issues causing the same error message.

This one worked for me [Windows Phone deploy Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292782/windows-phone-deploy-issue)

Essentially you need to remove/uninstall the device from Windows. Then after unplugging and plugging back in, the device and drivers are reinstalled.

Comment: After a random reboot, i started experiencing the same on my Lumia 640xl. Switching off/on developer mode didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many of the suggested solutions to no avail.

After changing the USB-C cable from a USB 3.1 port to a USB 2.0 port on my computer, the error goes away. YMMV

Comment: this one worked for me. somehow the device was not recognized over USB 3.1

Answer (score 1):

I see it is quite an old post...but I still get this problem. In my case, this happened after I deployed to a second phone I had for testing. After that, VS 2017 now only wants to deploy to that phone and not to the other phone no more. If I start another project, the other phone is recognized and deployable to (listed as device under debug).
Restarting system fixes this...

Also, if I add another project as reference (like a background task) to my project, I will loose the ability to select the devices and emulators under debug. VS 2017 simply then seems to deploy to the last device selected...(really no clue what this is). I have not been able to get the selection of emulators and devices back yet on this one. I only will have the "Start" and "Download new emulators" options. I think this has to do with the fact that VS maybe doesn't know the type (like arm/86/64) of the reference project because it is not set (not needed as this defies the purpose of referencing a project for dynamic references and not the compiled device specific file...)

Hope it helps someone ....

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the existing version of the app in device and re-ran it and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I got that error for a really simple reason...just opened a new solution I downloaded from GitHub, pressed F5, and got it!

I had left my build configuration in the default "Debug - ARM" setting, when I changed to "Debug - x64" it worked fine!

(Just adding another reason for completeness, not likely to affect your case!)

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful for others... I got: DEP6701 bootstrapping failed ... access denied.

Thanks to comments here, I only dev-locked then dev-unlocked my phone (was originally dev-unlocked). Totally works now (took some time installing missing frameworks at first). All good.

Thanks

Comment: Does not work for me.
Can't deploy Windows Phone Unit Test project

Comment: Got the same error while updating VS2017 to v15.5.1 from 15.4.x. Tried to uninstall/replug the device, then deactivate/activate dev mode on the phone, then did Build -> Deploy Solution and... viola! It's working!

Answer (score 0):

One more thing could be tried.

Uninstall the existing app if any and then deploy from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try on another usb port. It worked