# Bootstrapping 'Device' failed WHEN deploying UWP to my device

Tags: deployment, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

Hope you can help me out with the following:

I saw that there is a similar if not equal question for this. However this is for **Build 10240:** [Error : DEP6200 : Bootstrapping 'Device' failed. Device cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652885/error-dep6200-bootstrapping-device-failed-device-cannot-be-found)

This are my specs:

- **Windows 10 Pro**
- Version 1511 (OS build 10586.63)
- Latest SDK installed
- Visual studio 2015
- **Nokia Lumia 920**
- Windows 10 Mobile
- Version: 1511
- OS build: 10.0.10586.63

Surfing on the internet I saw that one of the possible problems is that the **IpOverUsbSvc services** is not running. In my case that service sometimes is running and some times not when Windows OS has started. In case it's not enable I only start the service.

Even doing that I get the same exact error

Does anyone have a similar problem? or have found a fix or workaround for this?

Comment: To eliminate hardware issues, make sure that your device (Lumia 920) is properly connected. I am saying this because something like this happened to me as the USB connection was playing up. Go into Device Manager and make sure that none of the USB ports have the yellow warning icon. If there is one, delete it and 'Scan for hardware changes' by right-clicking on computer name (in the device manager Device Type tree).

Comment: I already had done that before. I tried again without any luck. I ran the installer again to modify the set up. Everything went OK. Now, the IpOverUsbSvc is running but I'm still unable to deploy to my device.

Answer (score 0):

Just faced the same issue. Tried restarting VS and services and it didnt help. What helped was

1. Unplug device.
2. Go to Devices and Printers.
3. Remove Lumia XXX. This will uninstall the device from your system.
4. Plug in the device again, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

MikePR,

All you need to do is,

**First approach:**

1. Login to dev center account
2. Goto Dashboard -> Account Settings -> Unlocked Windows Phone and delete your devices. This will work.

**Second Approach:**

1. Plug already registered windows phone device and unregister it.
2. Now you try the device which is not working and it will work.

Thanks.