# Windows Phone Registration, ErrorCode: 0x64

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop for Windows Phone 8.1. I do not own a Windows phone myself so I am using someone else's phone. When I try and register the phone for developer stuff (using the Phone Registration Tool) I get error code 0x64. The times are correct, I have tried with and without auto time on.

- I am running visual studio 2015
- I am running Windows phone 8.1 (lastest update)
- I have a developer account
- The phone is has a different Microsoft account to the dev account

What can I do to try and fix this?

Comment: You can try out the solutions pointed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652885/error-dep6200-bootstrapping-device-failed-device-cannot-be-found). Even though the question is different sometimes using these techniques will resolve the problem. Also try removing your windows phone device from the list of "Devices and Printers" and reconnect your phone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I posted a question which has now been answered.

[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37421935/6375113):

> There was a server side problem with the Dev Center that blocked device unlocking. It should be fixed now, so try again, though it may take some time to propagate.
>
> In general you should contact [Microsoft Dev Center Support](http://aka.ms/storesupport) with problems like this as it's not something anybody outside of Microsoft can help with.

It's working for me now.