# Error communicating with the Windows Phone Dev Center. (ErrorCode:0x64)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to resolve the following error:

> Error communicating with the Windows Phone Dev Center. Set the correct date and time on the phone, check your Internet connection, and try again. (ErrorCode:0x64).

I've checked our developer account and can see there are no devices unlocked so we haven't hit our limit. (We did have 3 devices previously unlocked but they have since been deactivated and removed from the account).

The date/time are correct and the device is connected to a valid Wi-Fi with Internet access.

Here is what I have done:

- I have rebooted the PC (Windows 10)
- I have rebooted the phone (Windows 8.1)
- On the phone I have switched the date/time settings to manual and then back to automatic
- I've factory restored the device to original settings
- I've checked local host files for anything related to windows/Microsoft/development
- I've restarted the IpOverUsbSvc service many times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a server side problem with the Dev Center that blocked device unlocking. It should be fixed now, so try again, though it may take some time to propagate.

In general you should contact [Microsoft Dev Center Support](http://aka.ms/storesupport) with problems like this as it's not something anybody outside of Microsoft can help with.

Comment: Caplan - I've already contacted Microsoft. They haven't been useful at all. All I get off them is a link to contact and when I contact them off that link, they too provide another link. The latest being https://gethelp.live.com/pages/mso_eform.aspx?channel=chat&locale=en-us&product=wp8&topic=apps%20and%20store&wa=wsignin1.0 which doesn't work. I've added the issue in the Microsoft Community hoping Microsoft see it. I probably should have mentioned that. I've just tried and I'm still getting the same error however I will continue to try and hope. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It's now working, I've just rebooted and tried again. Many thanks!

Comment: THANKS!!!  This was driving me nuts.

BTW: I just tried again and received an error at the last step of the Windows Phone Developer Registration tool with the standard message about the IpOverUsbSvc service.  However, after a reboot of the phone, a Nokia Boot Manager installer pops up in Windows and unlocks the phone.  Don't forget that last step.

Comment: Ryan that's a good point well made. I'm using a different device (Honeywell D75e so will hit slightly different issues). I got the IpOverUsbSvc issue but it registered the device nonetheless. Glad you're sorted though as I know how frustrating it was!

Answer (score 2):

I just got this.

Nothing worked until I finally connected to a Internet capable wireless network.

Hope this helps someone else.