# Latest Windows version 1607 of build 14931.100-- UWP app not deploying to device

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

After updating to latest Version of windows.  On my lumia 630 running version 10.0.10586.545. The app isnt getting deployed but it pops up

> Windows 10 UWP deployment error Severity Code Description Project File
>   Line Suppression State Error DEP0001 : Unexpected Error: -2147023728

Whereas the same thing works when deployed to 10.0.10586.0 Emulator. and on desktop also.

For my Lumia 920 it pops up an error stating

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found.
>   0x89731810: Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected.
>   Make sure a phone is connected and powered on.

whereas I am able to browse folders inside my lumia devices.

*I have tried some of the suggested method*
 
1) [Developer option on/off](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691091) 
 
2) [Registry addition method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33667162)
3) Adding latest mobile emulator Insider Preview build
4) IP over USB service is running
5) Phone is in Developer mode.
6) Repair and modifying VS also didnt work.

Comment: Does the device show in Explorer?

Comment: update to todays released build: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2016/11/03/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-14959-for-mobile-and-pc/#orMQcDgcptWD7dZk.97 and look what happens here

Comment: @RowlandShaw yes device is showing up in explorer and is accessible.  magicandre1981 On lumia 630 with fast ring have yet to receive the new update. Its still running V:-1511  OS:-10.0.10586.545

Comment: Just now checked on Lumia 730 v1607 build 14946.1000 and its deploying. Will try a hard reset on earlier two devices now.

Comment: Did you rerun the Windows Developer Registration for the 920?

Comment: Yes tried to rerun but 920 is not being identified by registration when connected. Doing a hard reset on Lumia 630 worked. But am reluctant to do a hard reset of my lumia 920 being a personal phone. Any solution by which I can avoid that