# Visual Studio Community 2015 strange issue for deploying UWP app

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I already post a similar issue two month ago (may be on other forums), but in the same time I had to do a clean install which had resolved issue.

Today, I don't want to see a clean install as a solution!

I use Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 2.

My issue is when I want to deploy on my device (Lumia 930), I get this error:

> DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731810:
>   Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a
>   phone is connected and powered on.

I tried to deploy the same project from my other computer with Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (student license) and it works well.

I tried all solution I found on the Internet:

- restart developer mode (deploying and restarting VS)
- restart computer
- restart IpOverUsb (which running correctly)
- restart phone

I have no other idea.

Comment: Note I'am currently installing Update 3... but I don't believe this is the cause of my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see this similar problem on this stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292782/windows-phone-deploy-issue).

As they mentioned on that question:

> When the device is connected to the computer, in the taskbar click in the icon which shows that a device is connected (the one where you can "Safely remove" the device) and right click on it and select the show devices and printers option. When it opens, you will see all the windows phone devices you have connected to the computer. Disconnect your device and uninstall it and its drivers by selecting the appropriate option after right clicking on it.

Source for this answer stackoverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292782/windows-phone-deploy-issue).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this solution as soon as the update will be completed (update 3). Also, I tried a similar solution: uninstall windows phone device from the device manager.

Comment: Okay Almir Vuk, your solution works well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am glad to hear that!

Comment: If an answer to a question already exists, you shouldn't copy that answer, and re-post it. Instead, call out that the question is a duplicate (and vote to close it, as soon as you have enough reputation).

Comment: Yea I am aware of that but I am at very low right now only 59... before this question I had 44, I referenced that possible duplicate post, which is older but with two urls I noted that source for answer.... I just flagged it as duplicate.